# Designing SQL database for an item with multiple names

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I am creating a table for dietary_supplement where a supplement can have many ingredients.

I am having trouble designing the table for the ingredients.
The issue is that an ingredient can have many names or an acronym.

For example, vitaminB1 has other names like Thiamine and thiamin.
An acronym BHA can stand for both Butylated hydroxyanisole and beta hydroxy acid(this is actually an ingredient for skincare products but I am using it anyways because it makes a good example).

I am also concerned about the spacing and "-". For example, someone can spell vitaminA without spacing and someone can write vitamin A. Also, beta hydroxy acid can also be written as β-hydroxy acid(with "-") or β hydroxy acid(without "-").

What I have in mind are 2 options)

1) put all the names for one ingredient in a column using semi-colon to distinguish between names. eg) beta hydroxy acid;BHA;β-hydroxy acid;β hydroxy acid
-this would be easy but I am not sure if this is the smart way to design the database when I have to perform search actions etc.

2) create a table for all the names and relate it with a table for ingredients.
-This is the option that I am leaned towards, but I wonder if there are better ways to do this. And do I have to create separate rows for the same items with difference in spacing and "-"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a mapping table of 'name' to 'canonical_name' (or id).  It would have rows like

```
Thiamine   vitaminB1
thiamin    vitaminB1
vitaminB1  vitaminB1
B1         vitaminB1
```

By using a collation ending with `_ci`, you don't need to worry about capitalization.

When ingesting the data for a suplement, first lookup the `name` to get the `canonical_name`, then use the latter in any other table(s).

In that 2-column table, have

```
PRIMARY KEY(canonical_name),
INDEX(name, canonical_name)
```

so that you can go either direction.

Answer (score 0):

Create a table for ingredients and supplement and make a column that will be the same in table ingredients and supplement and just join them if you want to select

Answer (score 0):

It might be something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Ingredient (
      Id INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
    , ImagePath VARCHAR(63)
    , Description TEXT
    -- other ingredient's non-name dependent properties
);

CREATE TABLE IngredientName (
      Id INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
    , IngredientId INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL
    , IsMain TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
    , Name VARCHAR(63) NOT NULL
    , KEY IX_IngredientName_IngredientId_IsMain (IngredientId, IsMain)
    , UNIQUE KEY IX_IngredientName_IngredientId_Name (IngredientId, Name)
    , CONSTRAINT FK_IngredientName_IngredientId FOREIGN KEY (`IngredientId`) REFERENCES `Ingredient` (`Id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

Or you can add Ingredient.Name that would be the main name and rid off the IngredientName.IsMain then.

For spaces you should use some name normalization in your application such as removing consecutive spaces, capitalizing, normalizing spaces around commas, dashes etc. Sure, you can apply such normalization on database in trigger if you like.

There are some other possibilities.

You should think what would be user cases for using the DB first.
This is very important. There is no 'the best universal DB design'.
If you need some special search cases you might need special DB design or at least indexes.

P.S. I believe that putting different names in one field as something-separated value is bad idea